# Is there any difference between unlink() and remove() on a file?

Tags: c++, linux, unlink

In C++ on Linux I see that on the man page for remove() it states in part:

> remove deletes a name from the filesystem.  It calls unlink for files, and rmdir for directories.

So I'm wondering if there is any difference between calling remove() versus unlink() on a file?  Perhaps the only difference is that unlink() is slightly faster in that it does not have to handle directories?